# Apex Metadata API Security

Tags: apex, security, metadata

Is it possible to execute Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment method without Modify All Data permission?

I've got a setting which I'd like to place in Custom Metadata and update in Apex (via custom Lightning Component UI), but it seems to work only when running user has Modify All Data permission.

I've tried extracting update code to "Without sharing" class and to async context, but it didn't help.

Is it the same when Metadata is called through webservice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the metadata API, you need at least "API Enabled" and "Modify All Data" privileges. You might need more "Author Apex", "Customize Reports" etc etc but these are bare minimums. It is detailed in: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_prereqs.htm